# Difference between Len and Print Len()

Tags: python, jupyter

I've recently started doing data analysis in Python and since I didn't learn Python from scratch I feel I've missed a few nuances.

One thing I noticed is in one of my reports I had imported a data set from a CSV, put it in as a dictionary, manipulated it and was trying to print the remaining entries.

I used:

```
len(a)
len(b)
len(c)
```

When I did this only one of the numbers was returning and so I spent a significant amount of time debugging my code. In the end I found similar code online and tried to copy its syntax. The change that worked was:

```
print len(a)
print len(b)
print len(c)
```

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two commands. Initial I thought len just printed out a count, but I guess its something different?

Does len only have 'memory' for one count? Why do I need to add print?

Comment: The idea was already in your question. You wrote "and was trying to print the remaining entries" so that is where print is for. other ways would be to write (to a file object you opened before, or to place it in a variable. len(a) is as @self rightfully notes a statement that returns a value but not necessarily to some output. Some times the magic that helps often, irritates. One reason why in pytho we adhere to being explicit (most time). Keep up learning python and ask to be helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

len(list) does not print anything, it only returns. If you are using REPL (read - evaluate - print - loop) then it will print the returned value and loop. Therefore to print more than one you must call print.

[Here is the method documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_len.htm)

Comment: Ok so there is a difference between 'returning' and 'printing' and because lens is only returning what ever it evaluates it needs to kind of dump that in order to move on to the next evaluation.

If I want it more permanent I need to print which is kind of like letting the system write it down so it can move onto the next thing?

Comment: @AdamS.Cochran I believe it actually just keeps track of the last thing returned and will print that.

Answer (score 3):

[`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) returns a value, only in the REPL you'll see the value returned without assigning the value to a variable. More specifically,

> len(s)
>
> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may
>   be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a
>   collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

Answer (score 0):

You need print or write when it is not clear, that everything that produces some value needs to be echoed (like in an interactive session we call REPL Read Eval Print Loop).

So:

```
v = len([1, 42])
```

places the value 2 in v.

So in a script executed that has the following 3 lines:

```
v = len([1, 42])
len([1, 42])
print v
```

only one line will be printed (i.e. the last one with the value 2 being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way.

```
n = len(a)
```

sets `n` to the returned value.

```
n = print(len(a))
```

assigns `None` to `n`, because that's what `print()` returns.  Printing the value to the console is a side effect, in functional-programming terms, even though that is usually why you invoke `print()` on anything.

(In trad. Python 2 it was a syntax error, because `print` was a keyword.)

At the Python prompt, the value of `len(a)` also gets printed by the Python interpreter, but that's because the Python interpreter automatically does that, for your convenience.

In a regular Python program, basically only `print()` and `write()` etc produce output, and most operations (`len`, `+`, `open`, etc etc) only return something, without printing it.  (Think how noisy a program would be if it printed everything it calculated.)