# len(list) does not provide any result, whereas print(list) does. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my homework is building number of prime number counting code. This is where I come so far.

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime_list = []
    for n in range(0,num+1):
        if n >1: 
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0: 
                    break
            else: 
                prime_list.append(n)
    print(prime_list)
```

## Check

```
count_primes(100)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

I initially thought that using 'len' would provide the number of prime numbers. But when I change 'print' to 'len' Nothing happened.

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime_list = []
    for n in range(0,num+1):
        if n >1: 
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0: 
                    break
            else: 
                prime_list.append(n)
    len(prime_list)
```

I would appreciate if you show me some insight What I did I wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Len and Print Len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577127/difference-between-len-and-print-len)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is wrong, but I assume that was because of copying the code to the question.

The problem is that the `len()` function returns the value (i.e. the length). So you have to either capture that value in a variable or return that value itself.

Example:

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime_list = []
    for n in range(0,num+1):
        if n >1: 
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0: 
                    break
            else: 
                prime_list.append(n)
    return len(prime_list) #Returns len() of prime_list

print(count_prime(50)) #Prints returned value
```

This will return the length of `prime_list` to the print function, which prints it out to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! I have an follow up question.

Comment: Yes? What is it?

Comment: Also, if this helped, please mark this as correct (the little check mark under the votes)

Comment: n = [1,2,3,4,5]   len(n)  Then, it immediately present the answer. Why in this case, we need to use 'return' or 'print' to capture the value?

Comment: Are you writing the code in a terminal? If so, the terminal automatically prints out the data.

Comment: By terminal I mean the python command line interpreter.

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook. No answer came up after 'print(count_prime(50))' after 'len(prime_list)' is used. But, answer shows up if i use 'return len(prime_list)' or 'print(len(prime_list)' Does using Jupyter Noterbook makes difference?

Comment: Have you read my answer? 'The problem is that the len() function returns the value (i.e. the length). So you have to either capture that value in a variable or return that value itself.' When you just call len(), it calculates it but it does not assign it. When we return or print, it take that value and returns or prints it. Since you did not return the value, The print statement does not receive anything and thus does not print anything.

Comment: For example, just doing '2+3' outputs nothing. But if I do print(2+3) or answer = 2+3, print(answer), it take that answer and prints or assigns it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are careful enough, you may find that:

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime_list = []
    for n in range(0,num+1):
        if n >1: 
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0: 
                    break
            else: 
                prime_list.append(n)
    print(len(prime_list)) # changed from len(prime_list)
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. First of all prime_list is localized in the function so you cannot access that.  Also you have never called the function.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez The print is inside the function as well, so can access the list. And the call is in the question.

Comment: @Manuel, Ismail is right you can see that before the edit the code wouldn't have worked

Comment: yep I forgot to indent the code. the function has nothing to return. I just make the change as less as possible. Thanks for remind.

Comment: @Yash Yes, it didn't work, but not because of Ismail's nonsense but because of the obviously missing indentation (as in the question). With the indentation fixed in the obvious way, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Without the indentation it is technically incorrect, so I pointed it out. How as I supposed to know that it was a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime_list = []
    for n in range(0,num+1):
        if n >1: 
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0: 
                    break
            else: 
                prime_list.append(n)

    print(len(prime_list))
    
count_primes(100)
```

Basically  you havent printed it. So, use ***print(len(prime_list))***